# XSD : Restrict 0(Zero) from pattern

Tags: xml, regex, xsd, xsd-validation

Sample xsd

```
<xsd:simpleType name="test">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
            <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,17}"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

how do i change this pattern to block zero.  (is it possible)
more info:
0 should not be allowed
00 ,000,0000 etc should not be allowed
10 valid and should be allowed

Comment: What about leading zeros? `010`, `0xff`, `0abc`? Are they valid?

Answer (score 1):

Since XML does not support lookaheads, a regular expression that asserts this for a string up to length 17 might get quite ugly. But I think you can extract the length constraint to a separate restriction:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="test">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
        <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z1-9\-][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*"/>
        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="17"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Now the pattern requires one non-zero character (out of the allowed character class).

Comment: i was thinking of some pattern like first character can be a-zA-z1-9 and rest all can be a-zA-Z0-9

Comment: can u plz help me out to have this syntactically

Comment: @JAB then none of the three examples I gave in my comment would be valid

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is not to forbid the occurrence of 0 in a token, but only to forbid tokens consisting only of zeroes (so '10' and '01' are accepted but '0', '00', etc. are rejected), then perhaps this will do what you want:

```
<xs:simpleType name="test">
  <xs:restriction>
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,17}"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:pattern value=".*[^0].*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The basic idea is just to start with the type you already have defined, and then to derive another type from it by restriction, adding the constraint that every member of the lexical space must have one character other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`<xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z1-9\-]|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,17}"/>`

Comment: That will still allow `00`, `000`, `0000` and so on.